# IKVM + DatabaseLoader = Classpath issue

Tags: c#, java, sql-server, jdbc, weka

Weka in .net through IKVM works great.  The tutorial in Wiki is lots of
help. However, I think the way that weka loads the jdbc jar file is causing
some problems in .net. I wonder if anyone has encountered this problem
before and knows what I am doing wrong?

- I have compiled the sql jar using ikvmc: ikvmc -target:library
  sqljdbc4.jar
- I have included it in the .net project, and put DatabaseUtils.props
  in the proper directory.
- The jar that I'm referencing works great as a stand alone, but fails to find the JDBC once it is loaded through Visual Studio.

Thanks in advanced.

Here is the error output:

```
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://172.30.157.250;DatabaseName=Bidding;integratedSecurity=false;
ssword=expedia1
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:647)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:226)
        at weka.experiment.DatabaseUtils.connectToDatabase(DatabaseUtils.java:505)
        at weka.experiment.InstanceQuery.retrieveInstances(InstanceQuery.java:287)
        at weka.experiment.InstanceQuery.retrieveInstances(InstanceQuery.java:272)
        at clusterer.InstanceBuilder.getInstances(InstanceBuilder.java:29)
        at clusterer.Clusterer.getTripAdvisorClassified(Clusterer.java:85)
        at clusterer.Clusterer.main(Clusterer.java:39)
        at cli.ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(Program.cs:14)
```

Comment: did you found solution for this? I am facing the same problem...

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help to specify the `-classloader` option for the `ikvmc` tool when compiling.

Example :

```
ikvmc -out:outputDllName.dll 
-classloader:ikvm.runtime.ClassPathAssemblyClassLoader PathToJarsFolder/*.jar
```

where PathToJarsFolder contains all the `jar` files that were trying to load from the java `classpath`.

[Reference](http://old.nabble.com/Not-able-to-load-files-from-ClassPath-td31141788.html)